# How do I use multi-line patterns with QRegularExpression?

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qt5, qregularexpression

Qt 5.12.0

I'm using a class derived from QSyntaxHighlighter to highlight text in a QTextEdit widget. I've overridden the `highlightBlock(const QString & text)` function and I'm trying to make a multi-line regex pattern using QRegularExpression.

```
QTextCharFormat format;
format.setForeground(QColor(0xFF, 0x00, 0x00));

auto opt = QRegularExpression::MultilineOption;
auto regex = QRegularExpression("a(.|\\n)*a", opt);
QRegularExpressionMatchIterator it = regex.globalMatch(text);

while (it.hasNext())
{
    QRegularExpressionMatch match = it.next();
    setFormat(match.capturedStart(), match.capturedLength(), format);
}
```

This matches any string that starts and ends with the letter `a`, but only in a single line. I've tried several variants including:

```
auto opt = QRegularExpression::DotMatchesEverythingOption | QRegularExpression::MultilineOption;
auto regex = QRegularExpression("a.*a", opt);
```

...

```
auto opt = QRegularExpression::MultilineOption;
auto regex = QRegularExpression("(?m)a(.|\\r|\\n)*a", opt);
```

...

```
auto opt = QRegularExpression::NoPatternOption;
auto regex = QRegularExpression("(?m)a(.|\\r|\\n)*a", opt);
```

None of these work. Is multi-line regex just broken in Qt, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Could you give an example input, output you are getting and expected output for the regex? I just tested your `"(?m)a(.|\\r|\\n)*a"` expression and seems to work fine to me.

Comment: Maybe `highlightBlock` only returns a single line? try printing the block to see what you are working on

Comment: as @Felix points highlightBlock returns the string of a QTextBlock, and a QTextBlock does not have line breaks.